# Why npm start is throwing events.js:187 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event in my react project?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

While starting the server for the first time just after the code checkout 
    , my react js project is throwing error "events.js:187
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event" . I have node 12.13.0 and npm 
    6.12.0 . Log file attached [log file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B02xH.png)

```
events.js:187
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^



    Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
       (internal/child_process.js:264:19)
       at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
    Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:270:12)
       at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
    errno: 'ENOENT',
    code: 'ENOENT',
    syscall: 'spawn cmd',
    path: 'cmd',
    spawnargs: [ '/c', 'start', '""', '/b', 'http://localhost:3000/' ]
}
```

Comment: ENOENT - Error NO ENTry - No such file or directory

Comment: No log file available?

Comment: Here is the log file . https://i.stack.imgur.com/B02xH.png

Comment: which file or directory is missing @Jax-p

Comment: @Priyam  can you attach your package.json? Also try to downgrade the version of react and re install it. https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7061 this could help you!

Comment: refer from here @AyushiKeshri

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eVj5WgTaQSHOahJE_eN5c6yixYs_Ip_-

Comment: downgrade the version of react-script from 3.0.1 to 2.1.8 and try npm install @Priyam

Comment: @AyushiKeshri Downgrading the version to 2.1.8 worked for me. Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Downgrading the `react-script` **version from 3.0.1 to 2.1.8** worked for me.
Follow the following commands in sequence:-
`npm install react-scripts@2.1.8`
`npm install`
`npm start`

Answer (score 4):

If your system is windows, set your environment variable, add `%SystemRoot%\system32` to your PATH I met this error yesterday，hope it works to you.
Don't forget reboot you PC

Answer (score 2):

Try this if none of the above answers solved u..
Go to My Computer>Properties>Advanced and in the environment variables 
Edit the PATH and add the following

C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Users{yourName}\AppData\Roaming\npm

Add 4 of them and restart your PC

Answer (score 1):

You can use `node Your_File_Name.js` command to run from the localhost. To use npm start command, you need to use scripts array in your package.json file 
`"scripts": { "start": "http://localhost:3000/" }`
If this is not helpful can you attach more details?

Comment: can you attach the package.json file as well

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eVj5WgTaQSHOahJE_eN5c6yixYs_Ip_-

Comment: I don't see the dependency for `react-scripts` in the dependency array. You can use the command `npm install react-scripts --save`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to execute export `PATH=$PATH:/mnt/c/Windows/System32`. Change the path `/mnt/c/` to the path mounted on your wsl Windows (mount).

if it works, insert the path `/mnt/c/Windows/System32` into the file `/etc/environment`.

here in my case this solution worked

Answer (score 1):

I faces this issue while using the **windows subsystem for Linux** and solved it by adding `C:\Windows\System32` to Environment Variables Path. Environment Variables can add as follow.

go to

**control panel -> System and Security ->System -> Advanced System Settings**.

From the appearing dialog box, select Environment Variables, and then under System Variables select the path and select edit and add **C:\Windows\System32**. Restart the machine.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case this helps someone else, I started using react-scripts@4.0.3 from a version of create-react-app that didn't include it, and suddenly I got this error.

It turned out the hot reload websocket was attempting to make a connection from the browser to my dev server, but it failed and crashed the app.

I found the fix [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59363237/websocket-handshake-error-in-react-after-yarn-upgrade): I added `transportMode: "ws"` to my webpackDevServer.config.js beneath `hot: true`, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all the global & local packages that are being used in the scripts are installed, I've spent hours debugging an issue while deploying an application because `webpack-cli & yarn` wasn't installed globally & my project was trying to access it locally.

Answer (score 0):

In your *package.json* file try lowering the version of "react-scripts" to "2.1.8":

```js
"dependencies": { 
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",  
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.4.0",  
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",  
    "react": "^16.12.0",  
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",  
    "react-scripts": "2.1.8"  
  },
```

Above works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are experiencing this error on ubuntu simply prepend "sudo" to the npm start command. That is `sudo npm start`

Answer (score 0):

downgrading react-scripts to npm install react-scripts@2.1.8 works for me

Comment: It would be helpful to share context on why this solution would work. Also, "X works for me" is probably not the right level of confidence for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

in my case react-scripts was missing from the devDependencies adding it in devDependencies resolved it for me.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If **downgrading react-scripts not working** for you please follow below steps

1. Search **Edit the system environment variable** and open it.
2. Click on **Environment Variables**.
3. Select **Path** in **system variables** section and click on **Edit**.
4. Click on **New** and add this **%SystemRoot%\system32**
5. Click on **OK** everywhere and **restart the system**.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following environment variables to PATH. (System variables)

```
C:\Windows\system32
C:\Windows
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
```

They should be there by default but mine were missing for someone reason.
I added them and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem in windows, deleting the node_modules and then a `npm install` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case upgrading the Node.js to the latest LTS version (18.13.0) fixed the issue on my Windows 10 machine.