# Npm start command gives eventjs:187 error

Tags: reactjs, npm

I'm new to React. I created a new react.js application. But I can't start my application with **NPM** start command. I got the error below. My PC OS is Windows7 (32bit)

[Here are command results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sV9TF.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Two things here. Paste the output as code rather than a picture, that way it's easy for people to see the whole thing. Do this by editing your question and using the curly braces {} in the toolbar, or by indenting your code with four spaces. 

Second, I think you need to do more searching first. Looks like this might be an answer [Question 58603936](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58603936/why-npm-start-is-throwing-events-js187-throw-er-unhandled-error-event-in)

Comment: Thankss a lot.İ will definitely  try things which you have said next time.I hope that i will be able handle this