# Websocket handshake error in React after yarn upgrade

Tags: reactjs, websocket

In my react app, I connect to some websockets using the `websocket` package (*not* socket.io)

```js
 componentDidMount(): void {
    this.settingsSubscription = subscribeToWebsocket("Settings", urls.SETTINGS_WS, handleSettingsMessage);
    this.statusSubscription = subscribeToWebsocket("Status", urls.STATUS_WS, handleStatusMessage);
    this.studyDataSubscription = subscribeToWebsocket("Study Data", urls.STUDY_WS, handleStudyDataMessage);
  }

  subscribeToWebsocket(name, url, messageHandler): W3CWebSocket {
    let subscription = new W3CWebSocket(url);
    subscription.onopen = () => console.log(`WebSocket Client Connected (${name})`);
    subscription.onclose = () => console.log(`WebSocket Client Disconnected (${name})`);
    subscription.onmessage = messageHandler;
    return subscription;
  }
```

This had been working fine, and in fact does still work fine except I also get this error in the console:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/sockjs-node' failed: 
Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200

./node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js   @   webpackHotDevClient.js:51
__webpack_require__ @   bootstrap:785
fn  @   bootstrap:150
1   @   helpers.ts:1
__webpack_require__ @   bootstrap:785
checkDeferredModules    @   bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback    @   bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @   index.chunk.js:1
```

The error points to these lines in `node-modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js` which appear to be the culprit:

```js
// Connect to WebpackDevServer via a socket.
var connection = new WebSocket(
  url.format({
    protocol: 'ws',
    hostname: window.location.hostname,
    port: window.location.port,
    // Hardcoded in WebpackDevServer
    pathname: '/sockjs-node',
  })
);
```

I had just run `yarn upgrade --latest --exact` so I'm guessing that has something or other to do with it.

Especially since we use the console to demo to the client, I'd really love to get rid of this error message. Thanks!

Comment: This is weird... Are you using proxy of some kind between client and the dev server or between client and your own socket server?

Comment: I don't think so! And I don't think I changed anything besides upgrading my packages. This error didn't happen before today.

Comment: Web sockets shouldn’t respond with HTTP 200. One of the reasons it would return 200 is if there is a misconfigured proxy server between web socket and client. So, it might be an issue in webpack dev server or there is something else going on.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

we had same issue with ejected CRA project.

Solution of mine is manual update of the [`config/webpackDevServer.config.js`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/config/webpackDevServer.config.js) config file.

Imho this changes are the reason our livereload works again:

```
     hot: true,
+    // Use 'ws' instead of 'sockjs-node' on server since we're using native
+    // websockets in `webpackHotDevClient`.
+    transportMode: "ws",
+    // Prevent a WS client from getting injected as we're already including
+    // `webpackHotDevClient`.
+    injectClient: false,
     // It is important to tell WebpackDevServer to use the same "root" path
```

Comment: add `transportMode` & `injectClient` can resolve websocket problem, but HMR not work

Comment: thanks, i was looking for a solution to the problem two days!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when developing an azure portal extension on my localhost. I changed 'ws' to 'wss' and it worked.