# React JS can't run using npm start or yarn start

Tags: reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

I tried to run my react project with `yarn start` but it always shows the error like this

```
events.js:298
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:467:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)     
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:467:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn cmd',
  path: 'cmd',
  spawnargs: [ '/s', '/c', 'start', '""', '/b', '"http://localhost:3000"' ]
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I also tried run with `npm start` but still shows the error like this

```
events.js:298
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:467:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)     
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:467:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {   
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn cmd',
  path: 'cmd',
  spawnargs: [ '/s', '/c', 'start', '""', '/b', '"http://localhost:3000"' ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! myreactweb@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the myreactweb@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\jamal\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-10T17_47_44_268Z-debug.log
```

Even when I create the new project with `npx create-react-app blabla` and then start the project again, the same result still appeared.

Any solution to this issue?

Comment: Did you run `npm install`?

Comment: Maybe its help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58991590/12282249

Comment: @technophyle I did but still got some error messages.

Comment: @DenisStukalov Thank you. it solves the problem